# How to remove text between brackets in multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I have a big text files and I want to remove everything that is between 
 double curly brackets.
So given the text below:

```
String text = "This is {{\n" +
              "{{the multiline\n" +
              "text}} file }}\n" +
              "what I\n" +
              "{{ to {{be\n" +
              "changed}}\n" +
              "}} want.";
String cleanedText = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{\\{).*?\\}\\}", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text).replaceAll("");
System.out.println(cleanedText);
```

I want the output to be:

```
This is what I want.
```

I have googled around and tried many different things but I couldn't find anything close to my case and as soon as I change it a little bit everything gets worse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you need to also remove all line breaks? Can the `{{...}}` that are on the same level have single `{` or `}`?

Comment: That can be handled as another step, but eventually yes I want to remove the break lines as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew great man thanks, please post as answer so I can accept

Comment: There is one already working the way you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression cannot express arbitrarily nested structures; i.e. any syntax that requires a recursive grammar to describe.

If you want to solve this using Java Pattern, you need to do it by repeated pattern matching.  Here is one solution:

```
   String res = input;
   while (true) {
      String tmp = res.replaceAll("\\{\\{[^}]*\\}\\}", "");
      if (tmp.equals(res)) {
           break;
      }
      res = tmp;
   }
```

This is not very efficient ...

That can be transformed into an equivalent, but more concise form:

```
   String res = input;
   String tmp;
   while (!(tmp = res.replaceAll("\\{\\{[^}]*\\}\\}", "")).equals(res)) {
      res = tmp;
   }
```

... but I prefer the first version because it is (IMO) a lot more readable.

Comment: please check the answer by @WiktorStribiżew in the comments

Comment: I prefer while (text != (text = text.replaceAll("\\R*\\{\\{[^{}]*}}\\R*", ""))); if you can edit I will accept this. It's almost the same just more compact.

Comment: No, it must be `while (!text.equals((text = text.replaceAll("\\R*\\{\\{[^{}]*}}\\R*", ""))));`. Also, there is no need to escape `}`, they are handled correctly even when they are not escaped.

Comment: Thanks again @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This is {{\n" +
            "{{the multiline\n" +
            "text}} file }}\n" +
            "what I\n" +
            "{{ to {{be\n" +
            "changed}}\n" +
            "}} want.";
    String cleanedText = text.replaceAll("\\n", "");
    while (cleanedText.contains("{{") && cleanedText.contains("}}")) {
        cleanedText = cleanedText.replaceAll("\\{\\{[a-zA-Z\\s]*\\}\\}", "");
    }
    System.out.println(cleanedText);
}
```

Comment: mate I would change your condition as there might be case of '}} {{' which creates infinite loop,, otherwise looks great.

Comment: was about to write that

Comment: you can add ` && cleanedText.indexOf("{{") < cleanedText.indexOf("}}")`

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in regular expression, so I just write a loop which does this for you. If you don't have/want to use a regEx, then it could be helpful for you;)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {


    String text = "This is {{\n" +
            "{{the multiline\n" +
            "text}} file }}\n" +
            "what I\n" +
            "{{ to {{be\n" +
            "changed}}\n" +
            "}} want.";

    int openBrackets = 0;
    String output = "";
    char[] input  = text.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(input[i] == '{'){
            openBrackets++;
            continue;
        }
        if(input[i] == '}'){
            openBrackets--;
            continue;
        }
        if(openBrackets==0){
            output += input[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[My suggestion](http://ideone.com/S2kG1x) is to remove anything between curly brackets, starting at the innermost pair:

```
String text = "This is {{\n" +
                  "{{the multiline\n" +
                  "text}} file }}\n" +
                  "what I\n" +
                  "{{ to {{be\n" +
                  "changed}}\n" +
                  "}} want.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{[^{}]+?}}", Pattern.MULTILINE);

while (p.matcher(text).find()) {
        text = p.matcher(text).replaceAll("");
}
```

resulting in the output

```
This is 
what I
 want.
```

This might fail when having single curly brackets or unpaired pair of brackets, but could be good enough for your case.